# Boost.Python - Without using any boost for C++?

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I have developed a library in C++ (native) and have not used boost in any of the bindings.

I'm using Python to create a Wrapper for this library so it can work client-side. After looking at all of the available options to me, it was decided that `boost.python` was the chosen method. The question is whether or not I can use `boost.python` for the Python/client side of this, even though I did not use boost in any of the C++ implementation?

Also, assume that my library is called `myLib` is it therefore possible to have:

`myLib.Vector()` where I can push values to it? i.e. `vect = myLib.Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Without having to create a class called `Vector` inside of the C++ library?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost.python and ignore the rest of boost.

You can explicitely instantiate a vector template specialization in a .cpp file

```
template class vector<int>;
```

and later expose it in your python code:

```
class_<...>("Vector").def(...);
```

This way it should work.